# Two questions, executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object problem and 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

!pip install selenium
!pip install chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path')
browser.get('url')
elem_h2 = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'class_name')
elem_h2.text()
```

This is what I wrote already, and The errors are saying [executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object] also, ['list' object has no attribute 'text']

I would really appreciate if you are welcome to ask my questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service('path')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
browser.get('url')
elem_h2 = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'class_name')
elem_h2.text()
```